# Syntax error occurring in the if statement. Not expecting a bracket

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, syntax-error, conditional-statements

I am trying to make a Batch Script to create users for Windows 10. But when I execute it it returns a syntax error which I don't understand.
Here is the code:

```
CLS

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
:PREG
SET /P nUser=Introduzca el numero de usuarios a crear: 

echo %nUser%| findstr /r "^[1-9][0-9]*$">nul

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    ECHO No se ha introducido una cantidad correcta de usuarios a crear. Se introdujo %nUser%
    ECHO %TIME%;%DATE%;No se ha introducido una cantidad correcta de usuarios a crear. Se introdujo %nUser% >> ERRORUSER.LOG
    GOTO :PREG
)

IF %nUser% LSS 3 (

    ECHO La cantidad introducida no puede ser menor de 3.
    ECHO %TIME%;%DATE%;La cantidad introducida no puede ser menor de 3. >> ERRORUSER.LOG
    GOTO :PREG

) ELSE (

    IF %nUser% GTR 20 (

        ECHO La cantidad introducida no puede ser mayor de 20
        ECHO %TIME%;%DATE%;La cantidad introducida no puede ser mayor de 20. >> ERRORUSER.LOG
        GOTO :PREG

    ) ELSE (

        FOR /F %%A IN ('wmic useraccount get name ^| FINDSTR Alumno') DO (
            SET nombre=%%A
        )

        ECHO !nombre!

        IF "%nombre%" == "" (

            FOR /L %%i (1, 1, %nUser%) DO (
                SET CON=Abcd%%i
                SET ALUMNO=Alumno%%i
                NET USER /ADD !ALUMNO! !CON!

                ECHO Alumno: !ALUMNO!; Contraseña !CON!. >> SALIDACLAVE.TXT
            )

        ) ELSE (

            SET NUM=!nombre:~6,100!
            ECHO !NUM!

            SET /A AUX=!NUM! + 20

            FOR /L %%i (!NUM!, 1, %AUX%) DO (
                ECHO %%i
            )
        )
    )
)


ENDLOCAL
```

The error is the following:

```
(1 was unexpected at this time.
```

Using ECHOs I came to the conclusion that the error is occurring in the if in which I check that the variable is less than 3. However I am unable to see where the error is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `%nombre%` and `%AUX%` need to use delayed expansion.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. I am a little blind. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @Victorfori better use `cnt` or `contador` or whatever instead of  `CON` as var name, as it has special meaning -console-

Comment: I think that you could improve your code by omitting the majority of your `if`/`else` command structure and instead use your existing `findstr` command to filter out every input which is not a number in the range `3..20`.